# Using JavaFX 17 while using Java 11

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11, javafx-17

Is it possible to use JavaFX 17 with Java 11? I want to keep using Java 11 because I use it a lot and I don't want to switch over to Java 17. But can I run JavaFX 17 while using Java 11?

I have tried to find it on the internet, but I couldn't find it. The reason I ask this question is: I ran a script with maven where I could see if there were any updates available for my dependencies. This is what I saw:

```
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:display-dependency-updates (default-cli) @ testproject ---
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   org.openjfx:javafx-controls ............................ 11 -> 17
[INFO]   org.openjfx:javafx-media ............................... 11 -> 17
```

Comment: Yes, javafx has it's own version numbers. javafx 17 does not require java 17. You can try the hello world pom.xml files for javafx 17 with java 11 and maven rather easily.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx17/doc-files/release-notes-17.md _"JavaFX 17 requires JDK 11 or later."_

Comment: Always read the documentation before posting here.